# Best way to cool a tank of milk

Tags: design, cooling

I am not sure if I can ask this here - if not let me know which stack would be appropriate. I am currently in the process of making a robot that can make a cup of tea. However, I am having trouble figuring out the best way to keep my tank of milk at 4°C.

The tank has a capacity of 1 liter and is insulated using wall insulation I had laying around (similar to [this](https://s3.amazonaws.com/eakes-production/assets/13587/original.jpg?1546040749)). I am using relays that are connected to my Raspberry Pi (which runs my entire system) to turn the cooling element on and off, using [this](https://www.dfrobot.com/product-689.html) sensor. Outside temperature are usually above 30°C so no cooling is not an option.

I have tried using Peltier modules, they work, but are horrendously inefficient and I do not have the means to maintain that much power draw. Using a refrigerant cooling system would work, but I do not want to risk contamination as I have no experience dealing with refrigerants and have heard they can be toxic.

Would making a DIY [Bulk tank](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bulk_tank) work? Is that possible? I would also prefer if in the event of a power loss the milk remain cool for a couple of hours. I am currently lost so any advice will help, please let me know if you require any more information. Thanks!

Comment: buy a mini refigerator and use a peristaltic pump to lift milk through a hole in the refridgerator.

Comment: @joojaa I thought of that, but my machine is relatively small and there isn't enough space in the housing to fit a mini fridge.

Comment: How small are we talking here. I mean there are fridges sized fo individual beercans.

Comment: Or take the cooling unit from a mini fridge and use that on your proposed insulated box.

Comment: Water ICE and Dry ice (CO2) are used to keep items cold for (short) duration in the absence of a power source. Dry Ice seems to be how frozen meat appear to be kept cold when sent over postal service.

Comment: Well you could opt to use a vacuum flask (aka thermos bottle), maybe of bigger size and with a ice package inside it. This should keep your milk cold for a extended period of time with no heating elements needed, or you could use a peltier here as there's not much heat flow out of the flask so the petier does not need excessive amount of energy (something like [this](https://www.ika.com/en/Products-LabEq/Bioreactors-pg233/HAcf2-Cooling-finger-20112117/))

Comment: @joojaa the vacuum flask idea seems promising. if i just buy a normal vacuum bottle and drill holes in it for pumping, wouldn't that be a point for all the heat to get in? The link to the cooling finger you added, does not look like it can hold 1 liter. Do you think i could find something similar with that capacity?

Comment: You need to do everything though the cap.

Comment: For such a small load, the peltier should actually be a pretty good option. Micro compressor coolers are currently exotic parts. Imagine how much space your compressor would take up, and replace that with insulation, and your efficiency shouldn't be too bad.